# How to get hostname of another PC on network using IP address? (Batchfile)

Tags: batch-file

Looking to get hostname of a another pc on my network and assign it to a variable all within a batchfile.

I am looking to use something similar to below solutions:

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`hostname`) DO SET MYVAR=%%i
```

- This solution gets back the PC name but also .home at the end "PCNAME.home"

`for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%i in ('nslookup 192.168.178.1^|find "Name:"') do set name=%%i`

Comment: The solution to this was found on serverfault: https://serverfault.com/a/862578/300361

Comment: I tried this solution but it wasnt displaying the hostname for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET "MYVAR="
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('ping -n 1 -a 192.168.178.1') do if not defined MYVAR SET "MYVAR=%%i"
```

Above solution should work for IP addresses from the following IP address blocks ([private IP address range](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-a-private-ip-address-2625970)):

- `10.0.0.0` to `10.255.255.255`
- `172.16.0.0` to `172.31.255.255`
- `192.168.0.0` to `192.168.255.255`

**Edit**. *This returns `PCNAME.home` .. is there a way for the results to be just the `PCNAME` without the "`.home`" at the end?* 

The following code snippet treats even the case that `ping /a` does not resolve IP address to a hostname for some reasons.

```
SET "MYIP=192.168.178.1"
SET "MYVAR="
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('ping -n 1 -a %MYIP%') do if not defined MYVAR SET "MYVAR=%%i"
if NOT "%MYIP%"=="%MYVAR%" for /f "delims=." %%i in ("%MYVAR%") do SET "MYVAR=%%i"
```

Comment: This answers my question, Thanks you.